# Failed to send Message to channel - using spring cloud stream binder kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

upgraded springBoot 2.6.6 to 3.x , springCloud 2021.0.2 to 2022.0.x ,springCloudFunction 3.2 to 4.0
now junit is getting failed having Error -

`org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'filterName-in-0'  consumerDestinationName='topic_name_consumer'`

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel`
`cannot be cast to class org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.DirectWithAttributesChannel`
`(org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel and org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.DirectWithAttributesChannel are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

test properties file -

`Spring Cloud Stream Binding Properties`
`spring.cloud.function.definition=filterName`

## `filterName Binding (Consumer)`

`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.filterName-in-0.destination=topic_name_consumer`
`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.filterName-in-0.consumer.use-native-decoding=true`
`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.filterName-in-0.group=test-client-stream`
`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.filterName-in-0.consumer.start-offset=latest`

## `filterName Binding (Producer)`

`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.filterName-out-0.destination=topic_name_producer`
`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.filterName-out-0.producer.use-native-encoding=true`

FilterName implementation using reactor in service layer which is acting as cloud Function -

```
   ` @Bean
public Function<Flux<InputData>, Flux<OutputData>> FilterName() {
    return input -> input
            .filter(this::InputDataprocess)
            .map(this::OutputDataprocess)
            .map(testOutputData -> {
                return testOutputData;
            });
}`
```

// having seperate InputDataprocess and OutputDataprocess implementation

In junit flow is - Embeddedkafkabroker is aware about 2 topics(consumer/producer), kafkatemplate is sending mockdata(prepared by producer which is created in unit test context) to consumer topic, consumer(actual) will consume implicitly and  provide to filter then filetred data would be pass on to producer(actual), then it will publish to producer topic, from there consumer (which is created in unit test context) will read and validate the data.

No record found in topic this is the generic error message are getting while at last phase consumer (which is created in unit test context) is trying to read message from topic, in stacktrace getting above mentioned error message.

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=filterName
```

for upgradation removed stream , otherwise cloud function is not getting instantiated